# How represent hierarchy in ruby on rails and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I´m new in the world of ruby on rails and I´m making a site that have two types of user: 
USER A / USER B I found that they have much in common so I decide to create a parent class for those.

I dont know how to represent this in rails, I will have 3 tables? One for USER PARENT and then two more USER A AND B ??

And i´m using devise I will have to create a model for USER PARENT ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While it certainly is possible to do this with multiple models, a preferred solution might be to simply keep track of the user's role using a gem like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or [rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify), then specify what they can or can't do/see based on that.

Comment: But the user b and a have different attributes with cancan I will have one table users?

Comment: Yes, cancan would have them in the same table. If you want separate tables, you should be able to have them both inherit from the same parent model using `UserCommon < ActiveRecord::Base` and `UserA < UserCommon`.

Comment: And if I want to register a UserA , how would like be the form?

Comment: Each model would probably have their own controller/controller actions that you would be posting to.